# Getting SCORM data from Articulate (Questions / Answers) with as little code as possible?

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

**I just want to get questions and answer values from an articulate quiz.** really I just need {"question1":"value","question2":["values","values"]}

I don't care about anything else. I don't want to build/install a full-blown-lms to get the values of 5 questions from an articulate quiz. Is there **anything** that can get the tracking data from an Articulate file WITHOUT being a full-blown LMS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can publish to Scorm 1.2 or 2004, it doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you publish to SCORM you can create a fake SCORM API (JavaScript object) and intercept the values as they're sent from the course to the SCORM API (via cmi.interactions). Claude Ostyn's [SCORM Test Wrap](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/scorm2004testwrapwrap.htm) is a great starting point for building a fake SCORM API, if needed.  Claude passed away a few years ago, so his files don't include any support.

If you just want to perform a one-time extraction of the questions and answers, it's much more difficult.  Older versions of Articulate Quizmaker stored the quiz data in external XML files, which could be accessed via a script and parsed. Obviously, that isn't very secure, so Quizmaker '09 started storing the quiz data inside the SWF. This means any data extraction will require access to the SWF via either JavaScript or ActionScript. [JavaScript interaction is not officially supported](http://community.articulate.com/forums/t/9027.aspx), and if you want to use ActionScript you'd need to build a custom SWF that contains your ActionScript, then import it into the presentation before it's published.

Regardless of the path you take, much code will be involved. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. It is disheartening (to say the least) to see that this much effort will need to go into parsing this system just to get answer data from a simple survey. If I do come up with a solution I'll make it open source because frankly, this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I created this last year, it's open source, and can use PHP or ASP (the ASP version is more complete since that is what we use internally)

https://code.google.com/p/quizbaker/